# Watson Knowledge Studio - Pre-Annotate error

Tags: annotations, watson

When I try to run a Annotation in Watson Knowledge Studio I get the below error. "PREANNOTATE: The process failed. The selected documents were not pre-annotated because they contain annotations that were added by humans which would be invalidated as a result." What could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your documents were already assigned in Human Annotation Task and Human Annotator has already started annotation work. When such working document set is specified as a target for pre-annotation, WKS shows the error message to avoid losing the current work by Human Annotator.
Could you please choose original imported Document set as the target for pre-annotation, or create another document set from the imported set that does not contains any HA work.